# Outputting only the value of json encode object

Tags: php, json, object, encode

I'm currently trying to get a json object and display it
my code looks like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['search_button'])) {
$cnt = new Connector();
$employee = new Search($cnt);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$found = array('id' => $employee->getEmployeeByName($name)[0]['id']);
$emp_id =  json_encode($found);
echo $emp_id;
}
```

This works for me, the only problem I have is that I get an output that looks like this: 
    {"id":1} 

But I just want the value, so it should just display 1. 
How would I go on about doing this? I already tried it with json decode and str_replace to remove the brackets, but I didn't work out for me.

Comment: if you just want plain `id` then don't decode it

Comment: Then why are you encoding it?

Comment: @Jeremy wat exact output u r expecting?

Comment: @Elangovan just the value.
So for this example just a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either don't use `json_encode` at all:

```
$emp_id = $found['id'];
echo $emp_id;
```

...or only encode the ID (e.g., if you want quotes and escaping):

```
$emp_id = $found['id'];
echo json_encode($emp_id);
```

Comment: When I don't use json_encode I get " Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake... now it works, thanks :)